# How best to fix Chrome datalist rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

You may be aware that Chrome has problems with **datalist**/**option** autocompletes.

[image: Datalist in Chrome]

Essentially whilst it works in IE, Chrome doesn't allow you to scroll through the list and the list runs out of the browser into the main window.

My question is whether someone can suggest a good method of overriding the Chrome implementation, and what to override it with.  Solution has to work in main modern browsers and mobiles

Comment: personally I'm not impressed with native `<datalist>` at all. There are lots of scripts around for doing this

Comment: Datalists would be fine if they worked; I was trying to be fully HTML5 compatible and not use too much Javascript. Data

Comment: key there is "if they worked" but they are hard to work with IMO

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I searched for 2 days and ended up using https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

It is far better than datalist.

Comment: and there are numerous alternatives that don't require jQueryUi library or even jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl I completely agree.

Comment: @charlieftl feel free to suggest some. However I already have jQuery and jQueryUI in the application so using autocomplete may not be a bad idea.

Comment: Exactly my point. Most of the web apps will be depend on jQuery. So, why don't use the extend of jQuery?